# How do I add a new record ith belongsToMany and hasMany relationships using a pivot table?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I just setup model `Asset` with `belongsToMany` rooms and model `Room` with `hasMany` assets relationships. I also created a pivot table that stores both the ids of room and assets.

**`MODELS`**

```
class Asset extends Model
{

    protected $fillable = [ 'name', 'slug', 'price' ];

    public function room()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Room');
    }
}

class Room extends Model {

    protected $fillable = [ 'number', 'status' ];

    public function assets()        
    { 
        $this->hasMany('App\Asset'); }
    }
}
```

**`MIGRATIONS`**

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('assets', function (Blueprint $table)
        {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name')->unique();
            $table->string('slug');
            $table->string('price');

            $table->timestamps();
            $table->softDeletes();
        });
    }

 public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('asset_room', function(Blueprint $table) {
            $table->integer('asset_id')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('asset_id')->references('id')->on('assets');
            $table->integer('room_id')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('room_id')->references('id')->on('rooms');
            $table->unique(['asset_id', 'room_id']);
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

I added an asset via `php artisan tinker` as:

```
$asset = new App\Asset;
$asset->name = "Lamp";
$asset->slug = "lamp";
$asset->price = 40;
$asset->save();
```

Now how do I add an asset to a room so that it also adds an entry to the pivot table?

```
$room = new App\Room;
$room->number = 1;
$room->status = 1;
$room->asset...?
$room->save();
```

**`UPDATE`**

On Alexey's suggestion, I've updated the following function in `Room` modal since it's a `belongsToMany` and not a `hasMany` relationship.

```
public function assets()        
{ 
    $this->belongsToMany('App\Asset');
}
```

I created an asset with id 1. When trying to attach asset to room as:

```
$room->assets()->attach(1);
```

I get the following error:

> PHP Fatal error: Call to a member function attach() on null in C:\xampp\htdocs\hotel\vendor\psy\psysh\src\Psy\ExecutionLoop‌​\Loop.php(90) : eval()'d code on line 1

which also breaks the `Tinker mode (Psy Shell)` execution.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, since it's a many-to-many relationship, it should be `belongsToMany()`:

```
public function assets()        
{ 
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Asset');
}
```

To attach an asset to a room, use [`attach()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#updating-many-to-many-relationships) method:

```
$asset = new App\Asset;
$asset->name = "Lamp";
$asset->slug = "lamp";
$asset->price = 40;
$asset->save();

$room = new App\Room;
$room->number = 1;
$room->status = 1;
$room->save();

$room->assets()->attach($asset->id);
```

Comment: Thanks, Alexey. I think you mean $this->belongsToMany('`App\Room`') and not `App\Asset`. I already did that. On `$room->assets()->attach($asset->id)`, I'm getting an error: `PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function attach() on null in C:\xampp\htdocs\hotel\vendor\psy\psysh\src\Psy\ExecutionLoop\Loop.php(90) : eval()'d code on line 1`.

Comment: @anonym no, I mean `Asset`. Since it's a many-to-many relationship, both relations should be `belongsToMany()`.

Comment: Oh that's right, thanks, I corrected it. But I'm still getting the error. Any idea why?

Comment: Please show the code you're currently using and what exactly error do you get now.

Comment: @anonym looks like your model is cached or something. What does `dd($room->assets())` show if you put it after `$room->save()`? If it's `null`, you need to double check the syntax and clear the cache if you use it.

Comment: @anonym also, do you use `attach()` after you `save()` room as I've shown?

Comment: Yes, I did use the attach after $room->save() like in your answer. `dd($room->save())` outputs `true` in the console.

Comment: I did try clearning the cache, with the same result. `dd($room->assets())` yields `null`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161931/discussion-between-alexey-mezenin-and-anonym).

Comment: @anonym I've found the problem. I've copied your original code and changed the relationship type, but there was an error in the code. You must `return` relationship. I've updated my answer.